# Why isn't my linked Data Type Copy Constructor working?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

Here is some code that I have made that should copy all the nodes in a linked data type correctly, but it is not working. I have checked my logic and wrote it on paper many times, yet it still isn't working. Am I doing something wrong on this part of the code? Is my use of pointers to copy nodes accurate? The part of my Constructor test that goes haywire is the part that starts to print out what's in the queue.

```html
void LinkedQueue<ItemType>::CopyNodesFrom(const LinkedQueue& a_queue)
{  
  Node<ItemType>* orig_chain_ptr = a_queue.front_ptr_;  // Points to nodes in original chain
  
  if (orig_chain_ptr == nullptr) {
    front_ptr_ = nullptr;  // Original queue is empty
    back_ptr_ = nullptr;
    return;
  }   
               
  // Copy first node
  front_ptr_ = new Node<ItemType>();
  front_ptr_->SetItem(orig_chain_ptr->GetItem());
  
  // Advance original-chain pointer
  orig_chain_ptr = orig_chain_ptr->GetNext(); 
  
  // Copy remaining nodes
  Node<ItemType>* new_chain_ptr = front_ptr_;          // Points to last node in new chain
  Node<ItemType>* temp_ptr;
  while (orig_chain_ptr != nullptr) {   
 temp_ptr = new Node<ItemType>(orig_chain_ptr->GetItem() );    
 
 new_chain_ptr->SetNext(temp_ptr);      
    orig_chain_ptr = orig_chain_ptr->GetNext();         //Advance Our original pointer   
 new_chain_ptr = new_chain_ptr->GetNext();                   //Advance our new chain pointer
  }  // end while
  
  new_chain_ptr->SetNext(nullptr); 
  back_ptr_ = new_chain_ptr;
}  // end copy constructor​
```

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedQueue.h" // ADT Queue operations

using namespace std;

void CopyConstructorAndAssignmentTester() {
  LinkedQueue<string> queue;
  string items[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cout << "Adding " << items[i] << endl;
    bool success = queue.Enqueue(items[i]);
    if (!success)
      cout << "Failed to add " << items[i] << " to the queue." << endl;
  }
  cout << "Queue contains, from front to back, zero one two three four five." << endl;
  
  cout << "Checking Copy Constructor tester " << endl;
  
  LinkedQueue<string> copy_of_queue(queue);
  cout << "Copy of queue contains, from front to back, ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      cout << " " << copy_of_queue.PeekFront();
      copy_of_queue.Dequeue();
    }
  cout << "." << endl;
  /*
  cout << "Checking Assignment Operator tester " << endl;
  LinkedQueue<string> assigned_queue;
  assigned_queue.Enqueue("ha");
  assigned_queue.Enqueue("ba");
  assigned_queue = queue;
  cout << assigned_queue << endl;*/

/*  cout << "Assigned queue contains, from front to back, ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
  cout << " " << assigned_queue.PeekFront();
     assigned_queue.Dequeue();
    }
  cout << "." << endl;
  
  cout << "Original queue contains, from front to back,";
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cout << " " << queue.PeekFront();
    queue.Dequeue();
  }
  cout << "." << endl << endl;   */
}  // end copyConstructorTester
​
int main()
{
   CopyConstructorAndAssignmentTester();
   char a;
   cin >> a;
   //ConcatenateTester();
   //return 0;
}  // end main​
```

EDIT: Oh crap, this stumps more people than I thought. XD. I thought I made a blatantly obvious mistake.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: When I run my copy Constructor test it doesn't work. It's a copy constructor test given by my professor, so I'm assuming it is good. This structure seems to only copy one element of the list and print it out in an infinite loop

Comment: Okay, you know it doesn't work because it fails a test the professor gave you. Why does it fail the test the professor gave you?

Comment: I just posted the test code. The copy Constructor test fails and prints zero out over and over and over

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I'm having a feeling I'm going to have to start to learn how to use debuggers. The more that I learn in C++, the more easier I feel it is to make a mistake that is really hard to find, especially with pointers.

Comment: Can you post which string is being printed in the infinite loop, as you mentioned it copies only one - is it the last one or the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, and I'm finding it difficult to spot mistakes in your code lacking the full information of the states being manipulated.

The linked list logic looks all right: nothing jumps out at me as being faulty there in terms of the logic used to copy. Put in a distilled form:

```
first_node = last_node = new Node(other.first_node->data);
for (Node* other_node = other.first_node->next; other_node; other_node = other_node->next)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node(other_node->data);
    last_node->next = new_node;
    last_node = new_node;
}
last_node->next = nullptr;
```

I believe this is what you have and it should be correct in terms of the overall logic. Any problems will probably be found elsewhere. Nevertheless, it should make your life easier to reduce the number of states you're working with. This 'new_chain_ptr' is unnecessary and you can just write out the results to 'back_ptr_' directly.

However, I have a different suggestion. You have the rest of the Queue working correctly, yes, including these methods like 'Enqueue'? If so, your copy constructor can be more trivially implemented just using what works already. Start with the state for an empty queue, and then read the elements from the other queue and 'Enqueue' those elements into your copy. Now you can avoid getting yourself tangled up in the low-level linked list logic by utilizing the parts you already know are functioning like so:

```
// Create empty queue.
first_node = last_node = nullptr;

// Enqueue elements from other queue.
for (Node* other_node = other.first_node; other_node; other_node = other_node->next)
     Enqueue(other_node->data);
```

It might cost you an additional branch or so per iteration but remember that correctness always precedes efficiency, and you can come back and optimize once you have it working. Remember to handle self-assignment if the logic cannot work properly in those cases.

And yes, a debugger will give you a massive edge in accelerating the understanding of the nature of your code in addition to spotting mistakes more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips man. I will keep everything you said in mind. It's okay if you told me your mind, that's what I'm here for: honest advice. I always want to improve. I figured out my problem. My code was definitely okay, I guess when I made it with my makefile, it wasn't updating everything correctly. I must learn more about makefiles, I wager

Comment: Also if you don't mind a superfluous stylistic comment, unless you're required to do this via the assignment, I'd avoid a fancy get/set accessor interface for your node class (GetNext(), SetNext(), GetItem(), etc). Accessors are very important for information hiding to avoid making unnecessary breaking changes to your code, but your node class is just a private implementation detail to help you implement the list. It's not what people using your queue will access, so it's kind of overkill and will probably make things harder initially to provide a full-blown public class interface for a node.

Comment: The point of using a function like `GetNext` or `SetNext` and favoring this style of interface is to leave room to change what `GetNext`/`SetNext` do without touching the rest of the code. This becomes important if you're working with a million line code base that calls these functions in 10,000 places. But for a node class, that's a private part of your list. It's always going to be used only inside your list class. So that's why it's somewhat overkill and will probably make your life harder to favor a very OOP design just for a private node used in one place. For the queue class, it's good.